# How can I concatenate the results of a query in MySQL of diferent rows in one single column....see the description

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I'm this is my actual query in MySql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    clientescertificadosdescripciones.idClienteCertificadoDescripcion, 
    clientescertificadosdescripciones.cantidadClienteCertificadoDescripcion, 
    clientescertificadosdescripciones.tipoResiduoClienteCertificadoDescripcion, 
    clientescertificadosdescripciones.presentacionResiduoClienteCertificadoDescripcion, 
    clientescertificadosdescripciones.tratamientoResiduoClienteCertificadoDescripcion, 
    clientescertificadosdescripciones.idClienteCertificado, 
    gruposresiduosclasificacionesanexosiyii.nombreGruposResiduoClasificacionAnexoIyII
FROM
    clientescertificadosdescripciones
    INNER JOIN
    clientescertificados
    ON 
        clientescertificadosdescripciones.idClienteCertificado = clientescertificados.idClienteCertificado
    INNER JOIN
    solicitudesrecolecciones
    ON 
        clientescertificados.idSolicitudRecoleccion = solicitudesrecolecciones.idSolicitudRecoleccion
    INNER JOIN
    solicitudesrecoleccionesgruposresiduos
    ON 
        solicitudesrecolecciones.idSolicitudRecoleccion = solicitudesrecoleccionesgruposresiduos.idSolicitudRecoleccion
    INNER JOIN
    gruposresiduos
    ON 
        solicitudesrecoleccionesgruposresiduos.idGrupoResiduo = gruposresiduos.idGrupoResiduo
    INNER JOIN
    configuracionesgruposresiduos
    ON 
        gruposresiduos.idGrupoResiduo = configuracionesgruposresiduos.idGrupoResiduo
    INNER JOIN
    configuracionesgruposresiduosclasificacionesanexosiyii
    ON 
        configuracionesgruposresiduos.idConfiguracionGrupoResiduo = configuracionesgruposresiduosclasificacionesanexosiyii.idConfiguracionGrupoResiduo
    INNER JOIN
    gruposresiduosclasificacionesanexosiyii
    ON 
        configuracionesgruposresiduosclasificacionesanexosiyii.idGruposResiduoClasificacionAnexoIyII = gruposresiduosclasificacionesanexosiyii.idGruposResiduoClasificacionAnexoIyII
WHERE
    clientescertificadosdescripciones.idClienteCertificado = 8
ORDER BY
    clientescertificadosdescripciones.idClienteCertificadoDescripcion ASC
```

I'm getting this result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTHFj.png)

I need to modify my query to get this result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxMzD.png)

The MySQL version is: 8.0.23

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If nothing else you should shorten those names to something readable.

Comment: Research group_concat

Comment: Thank you very much @P.Salmon GROUP_CONCAT was the solution!